# Nodejs, email send using Nodemailer using Bluehost SMTP not being delivered, no error

Tags: node.js, email, smtp

I am trying to send email from my Nodejs application. I'm using the package [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com) for this. Here's the code I use for sending email;

```
let smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
   host: "box***.bluehost.com",
   port: 465,
   secure: true,
   auth: {
     user: <noreply@mydomain.com>,
     pass: <password>
   }
});

let sendResetPasswordEmail = (user, token) => {
   let mailOptions = {
       to : user.workEmail,
       subject : "Reset your password",
       text : _generateResetPasswordEmail(user, token)
   }

   smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, response) => {
       if(error){
           console.error(error);
       } else {
           console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
           console.log(response);
       }
   });
}
```

In the callback of `smtpTransport.sendMail` function, error is null and this is the response I get

```
{ 
   accepted: [ 'toemail@somedomain.com' ],
   rejected: [],
   response: '250 OK id=short-hyphenated-alpha-numeric-id>',
   envelope: { from: '', to: [ 'toemail@somedomain.com' ] },
   messageId: '<long-hyphenated-alpha-numeric-id@my-machine-name>'
}
```

Everything seems fine in the response, status code is 250, but `toemail@somedomain.com` simply won't receive this email. Also, I can't find it in my bluehost email dashboard's 'Sent' list. What could be going wrong.

Answer (score 6):

I encountered same problems. I was able to solve this by adding the name property on the createTransport object. name: "mail.yourdomain". If you do not see email, check spam folder. This was gotten from https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/677
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

This is my middleware setting for nodemailer, and it works well.
(I'm using Bluthost mail server)

```js
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const config = require("config");

const sendEmail = async () => {
  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    name: "mail.domain.com",
    host: "mail.domain.com",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: config.get("adminEmail"),
      pass: config.get("adminPass"),
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });

  transporter.verify((err, success) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log("Server is ready to take our message");
    }
  });

  // send mail with defined transport object
  await transporter.sendMail(
    {
      from: '"Name You Want" <email@address.com>', // sender address
      to: "reciever@email.com", // list of receivers
      subject: "Hello ✔", // Subject line
      text: "Hello world?", // plain text body
      html: "<h1>Hello! There?</h1>", // html body
    },
    (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log("Error: ", err);
      } else {
        console.log("Email sent successfully: ", response);
      }
      transporter.close();
    }
  );
};

module.exports = sendEmail;
```

Answer (score 1):

For your mail options you're missing from address. Make sure your from address domain has necessary dkim and spf records setup properly, otherwise most mail receivers will send mail to spam or completely bounce it.

```
let mailOptions = {
       to : user.workEmail,
       from : "noreply@mydomain.com",
       subject : "Reset your password",
       text : _generateResetPasswordEmail(user, token)
   }
```

Comment: Will I get a 250OK if the mail has bounced or got send to spam ?

Comment: usually 250 means recipients server is accepting the message , but not giving it to the recipient for some reason. Your smtp provider can't see anything beyond that. But if it does get bounced you should get one of the bounce error codes. For spam there it will give 250 ok so you need to setup your keys properly.

Comment: Try adding `debug: true` when declaring `createTransport`. I got this message from bluehost smtp service: `220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, and/or bulk e-mail.`